# Anchoring values for a rating or likert scale

Tags: database-design

I am designing a schema for an interview system as per the suggestion in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11970/76362).  I need to store several different types of questions:

- Questions with a free-text response
- Multiple choice text-response questions
- Likert (rating) scale questions.  This is essentially a multiple-choice question with numeric options.

I am keeping all questions in a `q_question` table.  Possible answers for multiple choice questions are kept in a `q_choice` table, with a foreign key to `q_question`.

I also need to store *responses* to questions.  I store responses to free-text questions in an `q_answer_text` table, and responses for multiple choice questions in a `q_answer_choice` table (with a foreign key into the `q_choice` table).

The question is, should I represent my Likert questions as free-text questions, multiple-choice questions, or something else entirely?

At the moment, the question-choice relation is one-to-one.  So if I stored Likert responses as multiple-choice, I'd have to either relax this constraint, or duplicate the choices for each new Likert question (since they all use the same scale).  If I just keep the numeric choice as a free-text response, I will have no way to anchor the numeric choice to a qualitative description (e.g. "strongly agree") in my database.

**Clarification regarding @MDCCL's notes:**

- The relation between `q_question` and `q_answer_*` is *ternary*, in the context of a specific `interview` (this part of the design is very similar to the one outlined in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120246/best-data-modelling-approach-to-handle-redundant-foreign-keys-in-relational-mode).  An `interview` maps a `respondent` (not shown) to a `questionnaire` (which is simply a set of questions).
- Yes, a question can have multiple choices for the likert response.  With the model I've come up with below, it would actually be a many-to-many relationship.  Then the same five choices could be reused across all likert questions (which are always on the same 1-5 scale).
- I am thinking about creating a ternary relation table among questionnaires, sections, and questions.  This would allow reuse of questions and sections across different "questionnaires".  This would be especially useful, for instance, in versioning.
- The more I think about it, maybe storing different types of answers in different tables is overkill.  Choices are immutable anyway (modifying the survey in any way should necessitate creating a new revision of a questionnaire).  So, perhaps just storing the value of the choice directly, in the same way as a free-text response, would be more sensible.

[image: DDL Structure]